# How do I kill the crab boss?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, donkey-kong-country-returns

In the Beach world, the end boss is at least one (I think three, though, if the cutscene is any indication) crab. I have no idea how to fight it! No matter what I do, it seems to hurt me, and I am losing red balloons like a toddler at the county fair.

How do I kill this boss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to defeat those Pinchin' Pirates, take note of a few things:

First, when a crab comes up with their claws, bounce on its head and it'll put it's claws up.

Second, when their claws are up (the music changes when this happens, shake-shake), do a ground-pound when they are close by to flip them over and jump on their undersides. Repeat this on the other two crabs, but pay attention to the music, because at certain points, the blue and red crabs put their claws up. Don't jump on them when while the claws are up or you'll hurt yourself.

After you've taken care of each colored (yellow, blue, red) crab at least once, they'll stack up into a tower of sorts. Get close (but not too close) and wait until all three put their claws up, then roll into them by holding the direction you want to roll to (on the D-Pad) and pressing <kbd>X</kbd>/<kbd>Y</kbd>. This all causes the crab tower to topple, and each crab landing belly side up.

Having Diddy Kong on your back helps as it makes it easier bounce (hovering helps you reposition yourself if needed) from one crab belly to crab belly, before they recover themselves. If you don't have Diddy for whatever reason, you can use the super bounce to get from crab belly to crab belly by pressing your <kbd>Jump</kbd> button a bit before you land on any baddie, this will cause you to bounce off it higher (useful for later baddies).

Once you've knocked them of their tower and bounced on all three bellies twice, you'll have defeated those Pinchin' Pirates!

Here's a video of how it's done on the Wii version -- the process remains the same: